# How to fix: Google Sheets API has not been used in project

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I want to built a questionnaire line chatbot and transmit the answer to google sheet.
Here is my code:
'''
import os

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort

from linebot import (
    LineBotApi, WebhookHandler
)
from linebot.exceptions import (
    InvalidSignatureError
)
from linebot.models import (
    MessageEvent, TextMessage, TextSendMessage,
)
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials 
import gspread
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta, time
import time


gsp_scopes = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

SPREAD_SHEETS_KEY = os.environ.get('SPREAD_SHEETS_KEY')
credential_file_path = 'credentials.json'
def auth_gsp_client(file_path, scopes):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(file_path, scopes)
    return gspread.authorize(credentials)

def records(A, B, C, D, E):
    gsp_client = auth_gsp_client(credential_file_path, gsp_scopes)
    worksheet = gsp_client.open_by_key(SPREAD_SHEETS_KEY).sheet1
    worksheet.insert_row([A, B, C, D, E], 2)
    return True

app = Flask(__name__)

LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ.get('LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN')
LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET = os.environ.get('LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET')
line_bot_api = LineBotApi(LINE_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN)
handler = WebhookHandler(LINE_CHANNEL_SECRET)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return 'hello heroku'

@app.route("/callback", methods=['POST'])
def callback():
    signature = request.headers['X-Line-Signature']

    body = request.get_data(as_text=True)

    try:
        handler.handle(body, signature)
    except InvalidSignatureError:
        print("Invalid signature. Please check your channel access token/channel secret.")
        abort(400)

    return 'OK'

user_command_dict = {}

@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=TextMessage)
def handle_message(event):
    user_message = event.message.text
    user_id = event.source.user_id

    user_command = user_command_dict.get(user_id)

    if user_message == '@問卷' and user_command == None:
        print(user_message)
        reply_message = [
            TextSendMessage(text='這是問卷'),
            TextSendMessage(text='B'),
            TextSendMessage(text='開始')
            ]
        user_command_dict[user_id] = '@問卷1'
    if user_command == '@問卷1':
        answer = user_message
        if answer=='yes':
            time.sleep(3)
            reply_message=TextSendMessage(text='問題一')
            user_command_dict[user_id] = '@問卷2'
    if user_command == '@問卷2':
        global answer1
        answer1 = user_message
        time.sleep(3)
        reply_message=TextSendMessage(text='問題二')
        user_command_dict[user_id] = '@問卷3'
    if user_command == '@問卷3':
        global answer2
        answer2 = user_message
        time.sleep(3)
        reply_message=TextSendMessage(text='問題三')
        user_command_dict[user_id] = '@問卷4'
    if user_command == '@問卷4':
        global answer3
        answer3 = user_message
        Date = date.today()
        today=Date.strftime("%Y/%b/%d")
        time.sleep(3)
        
        print(today, answer1, answer2, answer3)
        reply_message=TextSendMessage(text='問題結束')
        records(today, user_id, answer1, answer2, answer3)
        user_command_dict[user_id] = None
    #else:
        #print(user_message)
        #reply_message=TextSendMessage(text=event.message.text)

    line_bot_api.reply_message(
        event.reply_token,
        reply_message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

'''
I push it in heroku, but I get

> 2021-08-10T06:00:56.303548+00:00 app[web.1]: gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 403, 'message': 'Google Sheets API has not been used in project 10137149515 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=10137149515 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.', 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links': [{'description': 'Google developers console API activation', 'url': 'https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=10137149515'}]}, {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'SERVICE_DISABLED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'consumer': 'projects/10137149515', 'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com'}}]}
> 2021-08-10T06:00:56.304235+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.7.41 - - [10/Aug/2021:14:00:56 +0800] "POST /callback HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "-" "LineBotWebhook/2.0"

Please help and tell me what's wrong. THX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Google Sheets API has not been used in project 10137149515 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting

This is a settings issue in your Google cloud console account if you follow the link to your [project](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=10137149515)  When you set up your project you need to tell google which APIs you intend to use you have forgotten to add that you will be using the Google sheets api.

## enable google sheets api

Go to library on the left

[image]

In the search bar search for Google sheets api and select it then click enable

[image]

It should only take a few minutes then run your code again.

Comment: Thank you very much, DaImTo. I just solved my problem.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped you.   Accepting answers also improves your own reputation. Welcome to Stack Overflow